# SQL query - regex pattern for all alphabets

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I am working with Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

I want to perform a check for all alphabets from A to Z, special characters like: ":" and "-" for values in one column of my table.

I can work out the ":" and "-". How do I account for values between A to Z ?

I tried something like this but it does not perform the replace option for me.

```
INSERT INTO Employee (Name, PhoneNo, Sal) VALUES ('Joe Wang', '666 2323', 222222222);

INSERT INTO Employee (Name, PhoneNo, Sal) VALUES ('John Doe','666 2323', '2G23:22-2' );

UPDATE dbo.Employee

SET Sal = REPLACE(REPLACE(Sal,'-',''), ':', '') 

WHERE Sal LIKE '%:%' OR Sal LIKE '%-%' OR Sal LIKE '%[A-Z]%';
```

I get 'Sal' values as: 222222222 and 2G23222

The alphabets do not get replaced.

I checked online for the regex pattern and got [A-Z] for all alphabets from A to Z. Is my sql falling wrong somewhere?
It does not work if I substitute [0-9] either.

Please help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's failing because your `REPLACE` statement doesn't attempt to replace the letters, and you can't use a pattern match in `REPLACE`.

You should try a different approach and instead attempt to find any character that doesn't match the valid characters (Numbers?), and then replace that character.

[Here's a blog post that contains a UDF that does just this](http://codeslammer.wordpress.com/2008/09/02/sql-server-string-manipulation-removing-non-numeric-characters/):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.UFNG_ONLY_DIGITS (@StrVal AS VARCHAR(max))
RETURNS VARCHAR(max)
AS
BEGIN
      WHILE PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @StrVal) > 0
            SET @StrVal = REPLACE(@StrVal,
                SUBSTRING(@StrVal,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @StrVal),1),'')
      RETURN @StrVal
END
```

You could then write your update statement as:

```
UPDATE dbo.Employee
SET Sal = dbo.UFNG_ONLY_DIGITS (Sal)
WHERE PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', Sal) > 0
```

This won't be a very efficient approach, but if this is just a one-time cleanup, I don't think it should be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

make use of `REGEXP` and `[:alpha]` in your query something like

```
UPDATE dbo.Employee SET Sal = REPLACE(REPLACE(Sal,'-',''), ':', '')     
             WHERE Sal LIKE '%:%' OR Sal LIKE '%-%' OR Sal REGEXP '[:alpha]';
```

**[DOCUMENTATION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html)**
, hope this will help you